# Can someone explain to me the last step in this example problem? Using operators in a DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does $$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & D-1 & t^2\\\ 2(D-1) & -4 & 2t\end{pmatrix}$$

become

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & D-1 & t^2\\\ 0 & D^2-2D-3 & -t^2+4t\end{pmatrix}$$

If someone could explain this to me I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: What book is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way it would if $D$ were a real number: Multiply the first row by $(D-1)$, and add the result to the second row. This in order to make the first element in the second row equal to $0$.

Multiplying the first row by $(D-1)$ yields
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2(D-1)&(D-1)^2&(D-1)t^2
\end{pmatrix}\\
= \begin{pmatrix}
-2(D-1)&D^2-2D+1&2t-t^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Adding this to the second row gives you the new matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You multiply the first line by (D-1) and then you sum Line 1 and Line 2